# How to preserve form data when switching between tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

**Setup:**

The homepage has 2 tabs on it:

- Tab 1 has a form, which user fills out.
- Then he clicks on Tab 2.
- And then he comes back on Tab 1.

**Problem:**

When the user comes back on Tab 1, all the data he filled out is lost.

Is there a way by which the form data can be preserved?

As a side-note, Tab 1 has a "Submit" button. Submit button also clears the form once you click it, but there an option - `preventDefault()` by which we can control its default behavior and preserve the user-entered data after click. Just wondering if there is anything similar for tabs?

**Update 1:**

I am able to acces the user-entered data on Tab 2 by simply referring to the field name which is on Tab 1. So I guess the data is not lost.

**Update 2:**

Code: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pnuJT

Comment: Does the URL change and the page reloads?

Comment: You lost your data because the page got reloaded. Are you using this "http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/"? If you are using jquery tabs, it won't refresh the page at all and your data should remain the same.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: No, the URL does not change.

Comment: @JonasThein: yes, i am using the same.

Comment: @JonasThein, JacksonGariety: Updated question, please have a look.

Comment: Please post your code to. http://jsfiddle.net/ and update your question.

Comment: @All: Here is the code. Please let me know if it helps, if you need any more info, please let me know: http://jsfiddle.net/pnuJT/

Comment: @Learner why not copy all the content of an  html to a var tag and the reload it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `cache` option when setting up your tabs.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cache: true });
```

It will prevent the tabs plugin from reloading the tab content every time you switch between them.

[jQuery UI Tab Options](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#options)

Comment: Upvote and accepted. Works fine. But I still have to test for different scenarios. I guess I can apply this setting to selective tabs as well? Like `$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cache: [0] });`

Comment: I don't think it can be applied only to specific tabs. What are the different scenarios you are testing for?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you were using jQuery tabs in the comments but the jsfiddle didn't include that. Are you sure you are using this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

You could solve your problem pretty easy with using a plugin like that. The main issue is that you're reloading the page.